# Can't return objects from User class in Parse.com iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

I am trying to return users from my User class with a UISearchBar and UITableView. For some reason I can't retrieve any objects from the User class in Parse. Do you have any idea why I can't get any objects, even if there are a lot of users in the User class?

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
- (void)refresh {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    query.limit = 1000;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            [_refreshControl endRefreshing];

            [_people setArray:posts];
            [_tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"%@", posts);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching users");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the first line in your method with:

`PFQuery *query = [PFUser query]`

Comment: No problem, that used to always stump me when I first started working with PFUser queries. Glad to help